# Driving P-MOSFET with Netduino

Tags: mosfet, netduino

I've read quite a lot of threads here about P-MOSFETS and how to drive them properly from IC but still have some questions.
Here's the schematic:

[image: schematic]

Some useful values from MOSFET [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP27P06.pdf)
Vgs(th) -2..-4 V
Rds(on) ~0.07 Ohm
C ~1.5 nF

Schematic will be used to control a lot of common-anode RGB LEDs and current will be around 1A, so 60V/28A(max) MOSFET may be an overhead but that's what I got.
Can you please help me with the following
1. Will the schematic work as it is without NPN transistor controlling MOSFET gate?
2. Do I actually need current-limiting resistor to control Vgs or just the pull-up will do it?
3. Will MOSFET saturate on Vgs ~ -5V?
4. Will MOSFET close on Vgs ~ Vd - Vs = -1.7V?
5. How does the value of Pull-Up resistor affect how quickly I can switch MOSFET on/off (is 100Hz achievable?)

Comment: I have an equivalent circuit as the one in this question, except I’m using a 10k pull-up resistor and 12V on both the gate and source. The mosfet is conducting when my micro controller is powered off. Is that resistor value too high?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In general, simulating your design should answer that. Free tools like [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice) or [Qucs](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/) can be used for the simulation.
2. The limiting resistor is good practice. The pull-up resistor does not limit current drawn from the **microcontroller pin to the Gate**. This current may spike beyond the MCU's pin maximum if directly connected, for charging the 1.4 nF input capacitance of the FET. A **180 Ohm resistor** will be sufficient to limit pin current to under 28 mA, safe enough for many MCUs.
3. No. The Transfer Characteristics graph indicates a Vgs of around -6 volts required to saturate this FET, for Vds = -30 Volts. For Vds = -5 Volts and Vgs = -4 Volts (*not -5V, see next point*), the On-Region Characteristics graph indicates a current of well **under 2 Amperes**.
4. It should, as the rated minimum Vgs.th is -2 Volts, while the voltage divider formed by the 2 kOhm pull-up and the 500 Ohm current limiting resistor gives Vgs values of -1.36 Volts and -4 Volts respectively for MCU pin high and low. The problem you will face is at the pin=low part.
5. Yes. The maximum switching cycle (turn-on + turn-off) for FQP27P06 is `(45+380+70+190)=**685 nS**`. Thus worst-case switching frequency is around 1.46 MHz (*Vdd = 30 Volts, Rg = 25 Ohms*). Allowing a hefty margin for the much lower Vdd = 5V and the 500 Ohm current limiting resistor, **15 KHz switching** is definitely safe to aim for, much higher than the target of 100 Hz.

Comment: re MultiSim, I wouldn't call a 30-day trial a free tool.

Comment: @m.Alin Fair point, replaced it with a couple of other products instead.

Comment: It was a very detailed answer. Just to make it clear - can I improve situation a bit by increasing pull-up value to, say, 20k? And one more thing - is it safe to rely on results obtained wih mentioned simulation programs even for simple circuits like this?

Comment: @IgorRybalka You could use a pull-up of 20 kOhms and a gate resistor of 180 or 220 Ohms. That will increase the voltage swing of Vgs, resulting in a harder switching, and less heat generated in the MOSFET due to faster switching.